# Who else was programming dolls in the LA Dollhouse?

Tags: dollhouse

In a few episodes of Dollhouse,

> Echo is activated as a sort of sleeper agent

to send messages to Paul Ballard in an effort to keep him on task in his mission to locate and bring down the Dollhouse.

During the series, it is revealed that

> Mr Dominic and Boyd Langton are both traitors. Dominic is actually NSA and Langton is actually one of the heads of the company.

Since the messages sent to Ballard end when

> Mr Dominic is exposed and sent to the attic,

it is heavily implied that that person is injecting extra programming into Echo, but

> on multiple occasions, he has tried to kill Echo, or at least expressed wanting her sent to the attic. It also doesn't seem like Dominic would have the technical know-how to correctly hack the imprinting device or alter Echo's programming. There is also the issue of November delivering a hidden message to Paul *after* Mr Dominic has already been sent to the attic. Boyd might have the technical know-how to hack the imprinting chair/process, but sending messages also wouldn't make sense since he would effectively be bringing more attention to his own company.

Comment: I have a strong feeling this was a dropped plotline due to the cancellation...

Comment: No, proof, but I thought Alpha, had somehow remotely hacked the imprinting device as part of his plan to retrieve Echo.

Answer (score 4):

It was revealed that Dr. Claire Sanders/ Whiskey was sending the messages to Agent Ballard. The Episode where this happens is Briar Rose I believe. I'm looking for the scene but I believe it's after Ballard is in and right before the fight with Boyd.

Comment: source for this? i don't remember this ever being mentioned in any of the episodes.

Comment: @phantom42 Not sure if it's that episode or not but Ballard is in the L.A. Dollhouse and talking with Dr. Sanders/Whiskey.

Comment: Can you get a quote (or at least reference an episode/scene; I can get a quote if needed)?  I don't recall Whiskey or either Saunders having any skill in imprinting..  If nothing else, they'd have to be working with someone else, I think..

Comment: I can't find any reference in any episode guide or wiki about such a conversation. Whiskey and Ballard only overlapped in a small handful of episodes since she was missing for a good part of season 2. I'll try scrubbing through the eps if I have time in the next few days.

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't sure if it was perhaps Adelle DeWitt.  In season 2 Adele mentions to Harding that she has technical expertise.  Whilst Adelle hands over the technology that ends the world she also sent Echo to the attic - her real purpose being to find out why the attic was so important to Rossum.  Thus Adelle is a subversive character who sits just outside Rossum's corridor of power; and she has the know-how.
The other possibilities are Ivy - unlikely as Ivy was always striving for Topher's recognition; and Topher himself - his morality was hidden in the early stages, and it was announced that he was completely amoral.  He was, however, very moral.  Further, in one scene Topher displays a serial killer's brain - pointing to the dead part which is black and red, indicating a lack of empathy.   He then shows his own brain scan - the corresponding part on his brain is washed with thick white colour.
I hadn't thought of Alpha, but his focus was always so strongly on Echo it would be surprising if it was him.
I hadn't thought of Boyd either - he had something akin to a split personality, so it's not entirely out of the question.